# Running_total variable being reset - why?

Tags: elixir

I am extremely new to Elixir

The running total variable is getting reset back to zero after the
if statement. How do I fix this?

I understand that everything in Elixir is 'immutable' but knowing that
doesnt really help me.

```
defmodule Solution do
  @spec roman_to_int(s :: String.t) :: integer
  def roman_to_int(s) do
    roman_map = %{
      "I" => 1,
      "V" => 5,
      "X" => 10,
      "L" => 50,
      "C" => 100,
      "D" => 500,
      "M" => 1000
    }

    running_total = 0
    max_value = -100

    s = String.reverse(s)
    IO.puts("String is now: #{s}")

    String.graphemes(s) |> Enum.each(fn char ->
      curr_val = roman_map[char]
      IO.puts("processing char: #{char}")

      if curr_val >= max_value do
        running_total = running_total + curr_val
        IO.puts("greater than, running total is now: #{running_total}")
      end
      IO.puts("after greater than, running total is now: #{running_total}")

      if curr_val < max_value do
        running_total = running_total - curr_val
        IO.puts("less than, running total is now: #{running_total}")
      end

      if curr_val > max_value do
         max_value = curr_val
      end

    end)

    running_total
  end
end

IO.puts(Solution.roman_to_int("XIV"))
```

Comment: Enjoy this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56798122/1202324

Basically comes down that inside if block its a different variable... It does not get reset, It basically never gets assigned.

Comment: Thanks Danny, I'll take a look at that link. I did get round the problem through recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Everything is immutable" is in fact the important statement.  Every time you assign to a variable, it creates a new variable, and if that's inside a lambda or a block like an `if` expression, the new variable is scoped to that block.

At a mechanical level, one thing this means is, if you want to "reassign" a variable, you need to cover both branches if the `if` expression (in Elixir it is an expression and not a statement) and assign the result.

```
running_total = if curr_val >= max_value do
  running_total + curr_val
else
  running_total
end
```

However, there also is a similar problem around the lambda.  The lambda can't modify the variables at the outer scope, so it needs to return the new state from the lambda function.  [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3) takes an initial state and allows the function to return a new state.

---

How would I rework this?  The anonymous function keeps two pieces of running state, which you've labeled `running_total` and `max_value`.  You need to take those as a parameter to the function, and return the updated values from the function.  `Enum.reduce/3` will return the final state.

```elixir
{running_total, _} =  String.graphemes(s)
  |> Enum.reduce({0, -100}, fn char, {running_total, max_value} ->
       ...
       {running_total, max_value}
     end)

running_total
```

Within the function you need to make sure you reassign the variables, no matter which path of an `if` conditional is taken.

```elixir
running_total = if curr_val >= max_value do
  running_total + curr_val
else
  running_total - curr_val
end
max_value = max(curr_val, max_value)
```

Notice that `max_value` doesn't exist outside the anonymous function.  The function body can't modify it and it's not part of the eventual return.  As part of the state passed between iterations of the `reduce` call, it does get returned, but it can be ignored there.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code you can run:

```elixir
defmodule Example do
  def bind_in_scope do
    foo = "outer"
    dbg(foo)

    if true do
      foo = "inner"
      dbg(foo)
    end

    dbg(foo)
  end

  def bind_result do
    foo = "outer"
    dbg(foo)

    foo =
      if true do
        foo = "inner"
        dbg(foo)
      end

    dbg(foo)
  end
end
```

Results:

```elixir
iex(1)> Example.bind_in_scope
[example.exs:4: Example.bind_in_scope/0]
foo #=> "outer"

[example.exs:8: Example.bind_in_scope/0]
foo #=> "inner"

[example.exs:11: Example.bind_in_scope/0]
foo #=> "outer"

"outer"
iex(2)> Example.bind_result
[example.exs:16: Example.bind_result/0]
foo #=> "outer"

[example.exs:21: Example.bind_result/0]
foo #=> "inner"

[example.exs:24: Example.bind_result/0]
foo #=> "inner"

"inner"
```